# How to clip one word at the line-end, and the next word to the next line with CSS?

Tags: html, css

What I want:

```
_________
Thanks fo|r
your answ|er!
```

not:

```
_________
Thanks   |
for your |
answer!  |
```

and not:

```
_________
Thanks fo|r your answer!
```

Comment: From your example I assume you just trying to overflow the last word that passes an objects perimeter and break line after that one overflowed word. If this is correct why don't you just extend your object area, and if this assumption is incorrect please more accurately describe what your looking for?

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to do?

Comment: Does “clip” in the title mean that you really want the lines “Thanks fo” and “your answ”? If not, what then? And what should happen if the text is “Thanks supercalifragilistically for your answer!”?

Answer (score 0):

Use the width at which you want to break words for the element in question, then clip it to a narrower width using CSS `clip`. See http://jsfiddle.net/AEg3t/. However, I do not see any way to ensure that the clipping does not cut a letter in half.